# Core Data - Inconsistent preloaded Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have preloaded in Core Data the following `Pronoun` entity:
[image]

Once I load data from JSON files into the database, I print to console all items in this entity, with their siblings, with right data:

```
TOTAL PRONOUNS: 12
tú()
ellas(ustedes, ellos, )
ellos(ellas, ustedes, )
ella(usted, él, )
ustedes(ellos, ellas, )
yo()
él(ella, usted, )
nosotras(nosotros, )
vosotros(vosotras, )
usted(ella, él, )
nosotros(nosotras, )
vosotras(vosotros, )
```

Then, I copied the `.sqlite`, `.sqlite-shm` and `.sqlite-wal` to the bundle for my app, and I print again this entities but I don't get the same output:

```
tú
ellas+ustedes+ellos
ellos+ellas
ella+él+usted
ustedes
yo
él+ella
nosotras+nosotros
vosotros+vosotras
usted
nosotros+nosotras
vosotras+vosotros
```

Any idea why can this be happening?

Additional data:

- The xcdatamodeld is supposed to be the same.
- The loader app was done using swift, the app using the data in Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a `save` call to your context aftger constructing the `siblings` relationship.

Comment: I'm loading data to a lot of entities, and I call `save` after loading everyone of them. Should I call save after loading data to each entity?

Comment: I've tried to save several times while loading data, but I get the same results..

Comment: It looks like not having a reverse relationship for `siblings` makes the data inconsistent. Don't understand why, but I've added a reverse to-many relationship, called `sibling`, and now works as desired. Do you still want the code? (I assume you mean the code for loading pronouns and perhaps the json file structure)

Comment: Nope, you found it. It's documented that relationships need inverses.